# How to write the result of the multiplication of two matrix in a file? There are no proper answers yet

Tags: java

Write a program in Java, you have to input from keyboard two matrix with real dimensions NxM and MxP, multiply those matrix and write the result in a file, all matrix must contain double objects.

My code:

```
        import java.io.BufferedReader;
        import java.io.FileOutputStream;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.io.InputStreamReader;
        import java.io.PrintStream;
        import java.util.Scanner;


        public class MatriceMain {

            private static Scanner scanner;

            public static void main(String[] args) {
            try{
                            BufferedReader in_stream_char =
                         new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                         PrintStream out_stream = new PrintStream(
                         new FileOutputStream("out.txt"));

                         int N,M,P,i,j,sum=0,k;
                          System.out.println("Dati numarul de linii(N) si nr de coloane(M) ale primei matrici: ");

                          N = Integer.parseInt(in_stream_char.readLine());
                          M  = Integer.parseInt(in_stream_char.readLine());
                          double first[][] = new double[N][M];
                          System.out.println("Dati elementele primei matrici: ");
                          for (  i = 0 ; i < N ; i++ )
                             for ( j = 0 ; j < M ; j++ )
                                first[N][M] = Integer.parseInt(in_stream_char.readLine());      

                          System.out.println("Dati numarul de linii(N) si nr de coloane(M) ale primei matrici: ");
                          M = Integer.parseInt(in_stream_char.readLine());
                          P  = Integer.parseInt(in_stream_char.readLine());
                          double second[][] = new double[M][P];
                          System.out.println("Dati elementele matricei secunde: ");
                          for (  i = 0 ; i < M ; i++ )
                             for ( j = 0 ; j < P ; j++ )
                                second[M][P] = Integer.parseInt(in_stream_char.readLine());
                          double multiply[][] = new double[N][P];
                          for(i=0;i<N;i++)
                          {
                              for(j=0;j<P;j++)
                              {
                                  for(k=0;k<M;k++)
                                  {
                                      sum= (int) (sum + first[i][k]*second[k][j]);
                                  }
                                  multiply[i][j] = sum;
                                  sum=0;
                              }
                          }
                          System.out.println("");

                          out_stream.println();
                          for(i=0;i<N;i++)
                          {
                              for(j=0;j<M;j++)
                                  System.out.print(multiply[i][j]+"\t");
                          }
                           out_stream.close();      

            } catch(IOException e) {
                 System.out.println("Eroare la operatiile de intrare-    iesire!");
                 System.exit(1);
                 }
            }
        }
```

ERRORS:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at MatriceMain.main(MatriceMain.java:30)

How can you do it? Do I need to put the first and the second in two separate files? Is the code correct, properly?

Comment: There is not proper answer for this question yet, could you help me please? Redirect me to other link...?